# Integers satisfying $a^b=b^a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find all integers $a$ and $b$ that satisfy $a^b=b^a$, where $0<a<b$. By guessing I found that $a=2$ and $b=4$ is a solution. I'm not sure whether it is the only solution, though intuitively I think it is. How can I prove this? Thank you!

Comment: been asked before, though I don't have a link. try thinking about remainder when dividing by 2 for each argument.

Comment: it's (2,4),(1,1),(4,2),x=y

Comment: @MANMAID Do you know for a fact that the gcd helps? If you do, unless you explain how, your comment is unhelpful. If you do not, it is misleading. Once again, please stop spamming the site...

Comment: @Did Let, $b>a$, $\gcd(a,b)=g$, then $a=gk,b=gl$ and $\gcd(k,l)=1$, then $g^bk^b=g^al^a\Rightarrow g^{b-a}=(\dfrac{l^k}{k^l})^g$. Why do you think this might not help?

Comment: @MANMAID "Why do you think this might not help?" Oh, so you **also** need to learn to read comments.

Comment: I know for sure in this type of problem, if you use gcd in this way the problem becomes simpler, so @Did "for a fact that the gcd helps". Note that  since $\gcd(k,l)=1$, if you break into cases(which is not a hard thing to do here), only solution you can find would be $(1,1),(4,2)$.